# animate a view that isn't pushed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i have a view that i initialize in as my root view controller

```
UINavigationController *map = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mapView] autorelease];
    map.navigationBar.tintColor = NAGIVATIONBAR_TINT;
```

How can i animate the transition so that is seems much smooter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what transition you are talking about? The initial one when the view first appears?

Then you might want to take a look at *- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated* function that is called (duh) before a view appears on screen - and start some animation there. There is also its sister function *- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated* you might want to check out.

Comment: i would like a transition animation (i.e. the view should slide in). how can i do this in the viewWillApear ?

Comment: you could initially position your view 'out of screen' (ie set its frame to something like -480, 0, 0, 0 - depending on your device/screen orientation), then - in viewDidAppear do a standard ui animation and do 'view.center = center_of_screen;'